# NHibernate - can't get both sides of a OneToMany relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

## Context

We have Users and Invites. A User can have many associated Invites, an Invite is associated with one user.

I'm representing this via a column `usersk` on the `invite` table that corresponds to the `psk` primary key column on the `user` table.

There is also a concept of a Match, but that is only relevant to this problem to the extent that an Invite's primary key is a composite of its User foreign key and its Match foreign key.

I want to end up with:

1. User has a property that is a collection of Invites they're involved in
2. Invite has a property that is the User it's associated with

At a high level, my approach is creating a Set of the Invites tied to a User via a OneToMany relationship, and then having a ManyToOne mapping from the Invite to the User.

## The Error

Here's my ManyToOne setup:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => { 
    map.PropertyRef("PSK");  
});
```

Throws this error:

```
{"ERROR: 42703: column invit0_.user does not exist"}
```

Well that's correct, because there's no user column. But trying to specify what column to use gives me a different error:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => { 
    map.PropertyRef("PSK"); 
    map.Column("usersk"); 
});
```

throws an error:

```
{"Error performing LoadByUniqueKey[SQL: SQL not available]"}
```

due to inner exception:

```
{"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}
```

## Tools

MVC4 WebApi, NHibernate Conformist ByCode mapping

## Code

If I just try to get the first goal accomplished, creating a Set of Invites for a property on the User, things work swimmingly. That code is below:

User.cs

```
public class User {
    public User() { }
    public virtual int PSK { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invites { get; set; }
}
```

UserMap.cs

```
public class UserMap : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Lazy(true);

        Schema("public");
        Table("user");
        Id(x => x.PSK, map =>
        {
            map.Column("psk");
            map.Generator(Generators.Sequence, g => g.Params(new {sequence = "user_psk_seq"}));
        });

        Set(x => x.Invites, 
            mapping =>
            {
                mapping.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("usersk");
                });
                mapping.Inverse(true);
            },
            r => r.OneToMany());
    }
}
```

Invite.cs

```
public class Invite {
    public virtual int MatchSK { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserSK { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    #region NHibernate Composite Key Requirements
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        var t = obj as Invite;
        if (t == null) return false;
        if (MatchSK == t.MatchSK
         && UserSK == t.UserSK)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        int hash = GetType().GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * CONSTANT) ^ MatchSK.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * CONSTANT) ^ UserSK.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

InviteMap.cs

```
public class InviteMap : ClassMapping<Invite> {
    public InviteMap() {
        Lazy(true);

        Schema("public");
        Table("invite");
        ComposedId(compId =>
            {
                compId.Property(x => x.MatchSK, m => m.Column("matchsk"));
                compId.Property(x => x.UserSK, m => m.Column("usersk"));
            });

        ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => { 
            map.PropertyRef("PSK");  
        });
    }
}
```

With this in place, fetching a User gives me a populated Invites collection exactly as expected, provided I comment out the ManyToOne code in InviteMap.

## Conclusion

Help? I'm really hoping that this is some obvious conceptual issue I've missed. But... feel free to disappoint me on that front.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you could try to summarize your question. It's just about throwing your problem "as is" and a summary of what have you tried so far. I honestly believe this could be summarized in few words...!!

Comment: Thanks! I've added a summary to the top and condensed the rest of my explanation.

Comment: No problem. Why are you using `PropertyRef`? Use `.Column("PSK")`. Try that!

Comment: Yeah... that was definitely the right answer. My first stab at this was with a OneToOne relationship, and in that I used `.PropertyReference`, so I didn't even question using `PropertyRef` on this ManyToOne.  Using Column makes perfect sense.

Can I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: I've published an answer... I was ensuring I wasn't crazy about just changing to `.Column(...)` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found by discussing the whole topic on question's comments, the problem was so simple: it's about using `.Column(...)` instead of `.PropertyRef(...)` in your *many-to-one* mapping.